# ngFor in custom component

Tags: angular, ionic3, components, ngfor

I work on a custom component in Ionic v3, and I'm trying to use a ngFor.

In my .ts file I've this in my `ngOnInit`:

```
this.nb_stars = [];

for(let i=1; i<=4; i++) {
   this.nb_stars.push(i);
}
```

And in my .html I've this:

```
<div *ngFor="let star in nb_stars">
    test
</div>
```

But I've this error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since
>   it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
>         --> ]*ngFor="let test in nb_stars">
>
> "): ng:///ComponentsModule/CompStarsComponent.html@3:5 Property
>   binding ngForIn not used by any directive on an embedded template.
>
> Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all
>   directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
>         --> [ERROR ->]

If anyone can help me.

Comment: The syntax is `for of` not `for in`

Comment: I've got the same error with for of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `in` with `of` inside `ngFor` directive to get the values.
Basically `of` is used when we have to iterate over values and `in` is used when we have to iterate over properties.
Please find detailed code below:

```
<!-- Using of, which iterates over values -->
<div *ngFor="let star of nb_stars">
```

and

```
<!-- Using in, which iterate over properties -->
<div *ngFor="let star in nb_stars">
```

Also as per the error you received, you have to import the CommonModule in the root module (app.module.ts) as follows:

```
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule]
})
```

Comment: Thank, I had forgotten the CommonModule!